# Fixed element positioning relative to container

Tags: html, css

For a child div if I provide position fixed, it is positioning itself relative to the parent div. As per my understanding, a fixed positioned element is taken out of the flow so that it is relative to the viewport.

My question is why child div is coming inside main div?

Below is my code.

```css
#main {
  margin-left : 30px;
  background-color : red;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px
}

#child {
  position : fixed;
  background-color : yellow;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">Child Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not. It just looks that way. Set the top property to `0` and you'll see it sticks to the top of the viewport. You just didn't move it anywhere.

```css
#main {
  margin-left : 30px;
  background-color : red;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px
}

#child {
  position : fixed;
  background-color : yellow;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="child">Child Div</div>
</div>
```

Another way to see that it's actually fixed would be to add enough content after it so that you can scroll down and see that it is indeed fixed.

```css
#main {
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}

#child {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">Child Div</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```